# Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{n+i}{i+1} \le 1 + n(n-1) \ \forall n \in \Bbb{N}$ (without calculus)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, summation, proof-writing

I'm trying to prove the following proposition (I'm not supposed to use calculus):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{n+i}{i+1} \le 1 + n(n-1) \ \forall n \in \Bbb{N}$$

(I'm assuming that $0 \notin \Bbb{N}$)

This is what I've tried so far:

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{n+i}{i+1} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}[ \frac{n}{i+1} + \frac{i}{i+1} ] = [\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{n}{i+1}] + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i}{i+1} = n[\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i+1}] + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i}{i+1}$

Let $j= i +1$ . So now we have:

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{n+i}{i+1} =  n[\sum_{j=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{j}] + \sum_{j=2}^{n+1} \frac{j-1}{j}$

$= n[\sum_{j=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{j}]  + \sum_{j=2}^{n+1} \frac{j}{j} - \sum_{j=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{j}$

$= n[\sum_{j=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{j}]- \sum_{j=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{j} + \sum_{j=2}^{n+1} 1 $

$= (n-1)[\sum_{j=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{j}] + [\sum_{j=1}^{n+1} 1 ] -1 $

$= (n-1)[\sum_{j=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{j}] + n+1 -1 $

$= (n-1)[\sum_{j=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{j}] + n$

Therefore proving the following inequality is the same as proving the original:

$$ (n-1)[\sum_{j=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{j}] + n \le 1 + n(n-1)$$

If $n=1$ then $ (n-1)[\sum_{j=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{j}] + n = 1$ and $1 + n(n-1) = 1$

Now I assume that $n>1$:

$ (n-1)[\sum_{j=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{j}] + n \le 1 + n(n-1) \iff  (n-1)[\sum_{j=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{j}] + n \le 1 + n^2 - n$

$\iff (n-1)[\sum_{j=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{j}] \le 1 + n^2 - 2n$

$\iff (n-1)[\sum_{j=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{j}] \le (n-1)^2$

$\iff \sum_{j=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{j} \le \frac{(n-1)^2}{n-1}$

$\iff \sum_{j=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{j} \le n-1$

$\iff 1 + \sum_{j=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{j} \le n$

$\iff \sum_{j=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{j} \le n$

**And here is where I'm stuck.** I know that an upper bound for the harmonic sum can be found using an integral test but I'm not supposed to use calculus. Is there a discrete way of proving that $\sum_{j=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{j} \le n$ for all natural $n \ge 2$ ? Or maybe another way of proving the proposition without ending up with the harmonic sum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{j} \le n$$ is easy to prove of $n \geq 2$. Note that the inequality fails for $n=1$.

Indeed
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{j}=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{j}+\left( \frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)<\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} 1+\left( \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)=n $$

Answer (score 3):

You can use $$\frac{1}{j} \le \frac 12 ~ \forall j \ge 2$$

Therefore $$\sum_{j=2}^{n+1}\frac 1j \le n \times \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \implies \color{blue}{1} +\sum_{j=2}^{n+1}\frac 1j \le \frac{n+2}{2} \le n \quad \forall \;n \ge 2$$

For, $n=1$ it is easy to verify, that it's incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

It's slightly easier to show $\sum_{j=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{j} \le n-1$, so I'll do that instead (as you note, they're equivalent). In particular, note that *every* term on the left hand side is no larger than $\frac{1}{2}$:
$$\sum_{j=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{j} \le \sum_{j=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{2} \\
\leq \frac{1}{2}n.$$
So, all you need to do is show that $\frac{1}{2} n \leq (n-1)$ for $n \geq 2$, which follows immediately.